# How to control the data transfer rate in virtual network?

Tags: networking, virt-manager

I am using Fedora 20 as a host machine and in virt-manager i m install Redhat, and window7 when i am copy any data from fedora machine(Host) to Redhat(Guest) the data transfer speed is almost 5mbps now i want to increase and decrease the data transfer speed how to can i do this please suggest me.